# getSystemResourceAsStream unable to find resource

Tags: java, file-io, ioexception

I have a requirement to read a XML file from file system.

The code that read the XML is in a jar file and I cannot modify that code

```
ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream('Config.xml');
```

I tried setting the location of the Config.xml in classpath as well as path from command line

```
SET CLASSPATH=C:\opt\conf
```

and

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\opt\conf
```

But nothing worked.

everytime I run the code I get the exception

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not find resource Config.xml
```

Need some help in how to read this config.xml from the file system. I need to find a way to put the file a some location or set the classpath so that the code that I cannot modify can read the config.xml.

I already googled a lot and tried to implement the solutions but nothing worked.

Comment: The `CLASSPATH` env variable is not necessarily the truth. How do you start the application?

Comment: I am executing a shell script `java -jar encrypt.jar p password`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this using a different approach.

In the shell script that is executing the jar, I added a command to update the jar file to include the config.xml before executing the jar

```
jar uf encrypt.jar Config.xml

java -jar encrypt.jar P password
```

This will add the `Config.xml` to the jar if not present or will update if present.
And then when I execute the jar the `Config.xml` will be available in the jar.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method to read thiinks form a jar:

```
public Object[] readJARFiles(String jarName, String suffix) throws FileNotFoundException{
jarName.replaceAll("/", "\\.");
ArrayList<Object>objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
File f;
f = new File(jarName);
f = new File(jarName);
if(f.exists()) {
    try {
    JarInputStream jarFile;
    jarFile = new JarInputStream(new FileInputStream (jarName));
    JarEntry jarEntry;
    while(true) {
        jarEntry = jarFile.getNextJarEntry();
        if(jarEntry == null) {
        break;
        }
        if(jarEntry.getName().endsWith(suffix)){
        objects.add(jarEntry);
        }
       /* Object tempObject;
        tempObject = Class.forName(jarEntry.getName().
         replaceAll("/", "\\."));
            tempObject.substring(0, jarEntry.
            getName().length() - 6));*/
    }
    }catch( Exception ex){
    System.out.println("Error! in class ReadFiles -- " + ex.toString());
    System.out.println();
    }
    Object[] returnArray = new Object[objects.size()];
    System.out.println(returnArray.length);
    for(int n = 0; objects.size() < n; ++n) {
        returnArray[n] = objects.get(n);
    }
    return returnArray;
} else {
    System.out.println("There aren't files to read");
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: I need to read the XML form a location, means I have to put the file a some location so that the existing logic can find the file.